# How to structure regex for extracting variable value from script content?

Tags: javascript, php, regex

There is some data I have extracted from a script tag. And I need the content that is assigned to a variable.

```
var file = "some url here";
```

I want the regex to be structured in way that ignores all other text inside the `<script></script>` and only extract the url inside of the variable.

I was able to extract the data using javascript and I got this:

```
match(/var file = "(.*)";/)[1]
```

I just need the same line above but for preg_match() for php syntax.

Comment: With the same input string? or with its PHP equivalent?

Comment: Yes, the php equivalent of getting the contents inside of the script tag that is assigned to the "file" variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the same input string, the PHP equivalent is this:

```
$str = 'var file = "some url here";';
preg_match('/var file = "(.*)";/', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Output:

```
some url here
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/nlLmZ)